# CSS transform: translate() not working in Internet Explorer IE 9,10 & 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transform, css-transforms

I'm attempting to move an SVG element on the x and y axis using translate: transform(). It's working in Chrome however in IE it is not. I checked the caniuse site: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d and according to it IE supports it.

Here is a JSFiddle example which when run in Chrome the polygon element it moved 15 pixels on both axis, however in IE nothing is working: http://jsfiddle.net/mXgVE/20/

```
#Layer_1 polygon {
   transform: translate(15px,15px);
  -ms-transform: translate(15px,15px);
   -webkit-transform: translate(15px,15px);    
}
```

Is there a solution to this or is this yet another IE limitation to supporting CSS3 functionalities?

Comment: From the caniuse page you linked to, under "Known issues": *IE doesn't support CSS transforms on SVG elements (version 11 or prior).* I don't think you can do much unless you move the transformations outside of the SVG somehow.

Comment: Ohh thanks now I noticed the known issues tab! I tried using cssSandpaper however it says that 'non-Explorer browsers support the translate function as well. I have not been able to find a way to make this work IE at this time'. No solution yet for IE browsers regarding the translate() function.